# Perl - Why is my regular expression not yielding any results?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a small program that takes user input and is supposed to filter out specific lines from a text file which contains the specified "port". The text file looks like this:

```
State      Recv-Q Send-Q        Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port 
LISTEN     0      128                       *:22                       *:*     
LISTEN     0      128               127.0.0.1:631                      *:*     
LISTEN     0      100               127.0.0.1:25                       *:*
```

The script that I wrote simply prompts for user input and is supposed to filter out data using a regular expression combined with the input variable. Using the website *www.rubular.com* I can get my expression to work as intended but in the actual code I do not get any listed data.

Following is my Perl script:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $port_query = 1;
my $command = "ss -p -l -n -t -u -4";
my $port = 0;
my $output_file = "system_output.txt";

while ($port_query == 1) {    
    print "Please choose the port number (Numerical value):\n";
    $port = <>;
    if ($port =~ /^[0-9]{1,5}+$/) {
        $port_query = 0;
    }
    else {
        print "Argument not allowed.\n";    
    }     
}

system ("touch $output_file"); #Creates the output file.
system ("$command > $output_file"); #Executing system commands

open(INPUT, "<", "$output_file") or die ("Unable to write to file.");
chomp(my @socket_data = <INPUT>);
close (INPUT);

foreach my $line(@socket_data) {
    if ($line =~ /\S+?([0-9]|0*):($port)/) {
        print "$line\n";
    }
}
```

The script should print one line, namely:

```
LISTEN     0      128                       *:22                       *:*
```

Comment: `<` is the read mode, not the write mode, as your `die` message implies. Also, you do not need to store the output in a temp file, you can just store it in a variable: `chomp(my @socket_data = qx($command))`. And in that line of thinking, you can also skip the loop: `= grep /[0-9]:$port/, qx($command)`

Comment: Also, your script could be reduced to a bash script, using `ss ... | grep ...`

Comment: I know I can shorten the script quite a bit but it's for learning purposes. I have also tried the "grep" method too but I cannot get it to grep with enough accuracy.

Comment: @MajesticPixel There is no difference in accuracy between grep and foreach in that case. If you use the same regex, the result should be the same. Otherwise, you did something else wrong.

Comment: I see. I did not know that regular expressions could be used in conjunction with "grep". Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to remove the newline from the user input.

```
chomp $port;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Can't believe I missed that. Thank you very much.